# Android WebView Not Loading Images

Tags: android, android-webview

```
<div id="gallery-40" class="gallery galleryid-28208 gallery-columns-2 gallery-size-full">
   <dl class="gallery-item"> 
    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape"> 
     <a href="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390.jpg"><img width="1624" height="1080" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" data-lazy-src="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390" data-lazy-srcset="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390.jpg 1624w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-300x200.jpg 300w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-1024x681.jpg 1024w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-810x539.jpg 810w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-50x33.jpg 50w" data-lazy-sizes="(max-width: 1624px) 100vw, 1624px" />
      <noscript>
       <img width="1624" height="1080" src="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390" srcset="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390.jpg 1624w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-300x200.jpg 300w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-1024x681.jpg 1024w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-810x539.jpg 810w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2390-50x33.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 1624px) 100vw, 1624px" />
      </noscript></a> 
    </dt>
   </dl>
   <dl class="gallery-item"> 
    <dt class="gallery-icon landscape"> 
     <a href="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396.jpg"><img width="1624" height="1080" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAAQABAEACAkQBADs=" data-lazy-src="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396" data-lazy-srcset="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396.jpg 1624w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-300x200.jpg 300w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-1024x681.jpg 1024w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-810x539.jpg 810w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-50x33.jpg 50w" data-lazy-sizes="(max-width: 1624px) 100vw, 1624px" />
      <noscript>
       <img width="1624" height="1080" src="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396" srcset="http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396.jpg 1624w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-300x200.jpg 300w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-1024x681.jpg 1024w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-810x539.jpg 810w, http://cdn.androidkosmos.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/androidkosmos_Xiaomi_Max_2396-50x33.jpg 50w" sizes="(max-width: 1624px) 100vw, 1624px" />
      </noscript></a> 
    </dt>
   </dl>
   <br style="clear: both" /> 
  </div>
```

when i load this data into an android `WebView` it is not displaying images
the content is from wordpress site i used `json` api to get the data

Comment: @Rotwang No i was working on android app

Comment: @Rotwang when getting a post from wordpress site using json api it gives me html content i am doing some tweeks like adding some css and js file using jsoup lib and then feeding it to webview in my application

Comment: Let me try changing the size and let you know @Rotwang

Comment: @Rotwang it is not working even after changing the size

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks for your immediate solutions i removed the plugin from my wordpress site which gives that tags in the posts and it is solved thanks for your help

Comment: OK, I collected my meaningful comments to an answer. So that you can accept it and remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load a bunch of huge images: `img width="1624" height="1080"`.
It seems a bit **extreme**, to me.

I'd divide both dimensions by **4**, to start with something reasonable.
Then maybe tweak them more.

Aans also try removing all the `<noscript />` tags (or at least one, for testing purposes).
It seems you need to execute some server script for displaying the images.

Answer (score 0):

Android [does not support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) the srcset tag in OS versions previous to 5.0. It is possible that that is why your content inside noscript would not load. As for the content in the default a-href tag, it might not be loading because of the scripts. So, you will want to enable Javascript.

The following code should enable Javascript (change the View ID to your actual WebView):

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

have you added the internet permissions?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

add this permission into android manifest file.

it will surely work.

Comment: Yes all the permisions are okay i not just loading only this content i am getting the complete html from wordpress site other text is loading but the image is not loading